# Azure App Service Virtual Network integration on more regions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have an issue with Virtual Networks / App Service in Azure.
Following my resources of the app (two groups in two different regions) :

**1) Resource Group 1 - Japan East**

```
1.1) a Virtual Network  
1.2) a Virtual Network Gateway  
1.3) a Web App Service with Virtual Network integration on 1.2  
1.4) a Virtual Machine with Linux with a Network interface on the Virtual   Network
```

**2) Resource Group 2 - West Europe**

```
2.1) a Virtual Network  
2.2) a Virtual Network Gateway  
2.3) a Web App Service with Virtual Network integration on 2.2  
2.4) a Virtual Machine with Linux with a Network interface on the Virtual Network
```

**3) A connection Vpn-to-Vpn bidirectional form 1.2 to 2.2**

The two VMs **1.4** e **2.4** are able to communicate. E.g I can start a SSH connection from **1.4** to **2.4** and viceversa.
The problem is that the communication from **1.3** to **2.4** does not work ('connection timeout error') : I've deployed a NodeJs app in **1.3** that tries to make requests to a service deployed in the Linux VM server **2.4**. The application logic is correct because a test of communication between **1.3** and **1.4** goes fine.

Here the settings of the Network Security Group (I'd make a communication on port **10000**):

[image]

It is possible to configure this kind of infrastructure ?

Comment: Can you please take a moment to edit your question and format it properly? Pretty difficult to read as-is.

Comment: Do you mean you want web app service 1.3 can communicate with Linux VM 1.4?  please try to add inbound rules to NSG settings.

Comment: Hi David I've formatted better my question.

No Jason : I'd establish a communication between an App Service (**1.3**) in a ResourceGroup/Region different from that contains a VM (**2.4**) . A communication, jst for test, between two different VMs (**1.4** and **2.4**) is possible. I add Network Security Rules description on the original post but I suppose the issue is not related to those settings because the test with VMs goes fine.
Thanks.